# Fastlane appcenter upload not working, App not found

Tags: android, fastlane, appcenter

on a project I setup with fastlane a lane to build an android app and publish it on appcenter.

Here a snippet of the lane, where, for the sake of simplicity, I surround by curly brackets protected data:

```
lane :buildAndDeploy do
  gradle(task: "clean assembleRelease")
  appcenter_upload(
      app_name: "{myappname}",
      api_token: "{token}",
      owner_name: "{ownername}",
      owner_type: "user", 
      file: "{filePath}"
    )
```

Everything worked like a charm till two weeks ago, when suddently it stops working. When the lane cruise to the appcenter upload step I receive this from the plugin.

```
------------------------------
--- Step: appcenter_upload ---
------------------------------
App with name {appname} not found, create one? (y/n)
```

as indicated in the documentation the app name and owner name are populated like this:

[https://appcenter.ms/users/{ownername}/apps/{appname}](https://appcenter.ms/users/%7Bownername%7D/apps/%7Bappname%7D)

Any idea of what could have happened in the past two weeks? I didn't change anything both on the Fastfile and the Appcenter project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I discover where was the issue.

Running this command with appcenter cli
`appcenter apps list --token <MY_TOKEN> --debug`
I found out that the token I was using didn't belong to the owner of the project, instead it belonged to a different user who has been removed from the project.

Adding a new API token resolved the issue.